# Increasing the space inside a windows form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to populate my windows form with new controls and data based on what is read from my database. The left side of the form is a static panel which will not need re sizing but I need to create multiple labels on the right side which requires more space. I added the vscroll control but am having trouble increasing the size of the right side of the form.[image]

Comment: Don't do this.  Use a ListView or a DataGridView control.

Comment: Why not use a Panel on the right side which you dock and populate instead, and set the AutoScroll to True ?

Comment: @HansPassant would I be able to make a graphical interface with the grid view or list view?

Comment: @AbdiasSoftware Thanks man! I was making it harder then it was it seems.

Comment: No problem. I'll try to convert to answer so the post isn't left unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a scroll-bar will require a semi-low-level implementation where you need to always update the view by repositioning the elements, calculating your scroll-bar in relation to total view, what elements would be visible and so forth.

A better solution in this case will probably be to add a `Panel` control on the right which is docked (f.ex. Fill) and then set the `AutoScroll` property to `True`.

This way you leave all the "low level" stuff to the `Panel` control and you can add and position the elements you need to the Panel's `Controls` collection instead.